# An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, runtime-error

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> **Runtime Error**
>
> **Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.**

The above error occurs now and then on my PROD. *Recycling the application pool resolves the issue* but after few days the same error resurfaces again. I did browse through other post relavant to this topic but it seems this error occurs always for them which is not same for me.

Answer (score 9):

There is a server error on your error page, so the error page tries to redirect to the error page. To avoid an infinite loop, the request is terminated.

Use an HTML error page, rather than a .ASPX page.

Disabling custom errors will also 'fix' this, but, you don't want to do that on production.

You can also use ELMAH to log exceptions and then fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
<system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```